# Is it possible to get the list of user that had already gave authentication to your webapp (GoogleAppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried researching for a couple of weeks but I still couldn't seem to find a list of users that have already authorized the google webApp (login method - gmail).

I tried Users.all().fetch() but doesn't seem possible

Reason why I'm not building an entirely new model is because I already had some users that have previously gave the authentication, so I just need to confirm if there's already an in-build method that I can use to get those users' emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get this list from the Users service. You have to maintain this list yourself if you need it.

Note that when a user cancels an authorization, you will not be informed about it.

Comment: ok! thk you so much!  i'll just continue using the one i've planned then, thk you! I really needed to confirmed this :)